# How to enable the OEM unlocking option if isnt available in the developer options menu?

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, huawei, bootloader-lock, frp

Im trying to unlock the frp and the phone , based on `kirin 710` and `710A`, and there is no `OEM Unlock` option in the developer menu.

It has been issued the commands:

```
fastboot -s usb:1-1 oem device-info
fastboot -s usb:1-1 oem unlock
fastboot -s usb:1-1 flashing unlock
```

all with and without the `-s` argument, the phone is using emui 9, the usb cable is ok, and the phone is booted in fastboot.

All the commands report a

```
FAILED (remote: 'Command not allowed')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

AFAIK, this is because the `oem unlock` isn't enabled.
So, how can workaround this?
Thanks.

Comment: I would assume you don't find this option because your device does not support an official way to unlock it. Please read this blog post and the contained links https://www.xda-developers.com/huawei-honor-bootloader-unlock-potatonv/

Comment: Thanks Im reading the article and I will post what happened.

Comment: The thing the socs dont appear in the supported list, but Im going to try anyway.